# Disabling CStates/TurboMode in Windows

Tags: cpu, cpu-usage, cpu-speed

In Linux I know how to boot and have cstates disabled to get full CPU power.

How is this done in Windows? Does it vary based on Intel and AMD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the powerplan to `High Performance`. This disables all Power Saving features and runs the CPU all the time at full speed.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/power-plans-frequently-asked-questions